# Reg query and delete key based on data

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a reg query or call it simply a script that will search registry keys and delete the one based on data inside.

Key looks like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{D642433C-50B0-4F52-9BB7-1D4AF5E99FF8}]
"somevalue"="somedata"
```

CLSID is completely random, but data inside value is not.

Is it possible to write some kind of script that will delete this **{D642433C-50B0-4F52-9BB7-1D4AF5E99FF8}** key based on the data.

I tried to search for various reg/vbs/powershell scripts, but nothing even close to a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate all the subkeys under `Uninstall` with `Get-ChildItem` and then check if the `somevalue` value entry contains the desired data:

```
$UninstallKeys = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
foreach($Key in $UninstallKeys){
    if($Key.GetValue("somevalue") -eq "somedata"){
        Remove-Item -Path $Key.PSPath -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems it works. Now I have two questions:

1) What if I want to have this script matching 2 data strings? somedata1 and/or somedata2

2) How to run this script from run window? Something like powershell.exe /command ?